# Uno - PCA9685 Servos are too shaky before stabilizing - when using two channels

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, pwm, adafruit

I'm trying to control a [Tilt pan](https://www.amazon.de/Mini-Pan-Tilt-Set-Micro-Servos/dp/B00PY3LQ2Y/ref=pd_sbs_147_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=1FVW4X2PMYE8TM55X952) with an Arduino Uno. And the [Sunrounder servo driver](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B014KTSMLA/ref=pd_bxgy_107_img_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=F2QQAD84BXAF00N0YGCX) is used to do this, which comes with it's own capacitor out of the box.

The pan has two Servo motors, that help it face any direction.

I have set this up and even calibrated, so that I can input numbers between -90 degrees to +90 degrees horizontally, and 0 to 90 vertically. And it is working...

But the problem is that, when it is idle for too long, or when I connect it in the beginning, The tilt pan shakes intensely for about 20 to 30 seconds and turns every other direction before stabilizing to the correct point. As if it had a seizure!

When I disconnect one of the Servos, this problem solves. Two servos are connected to the first and second channel of the servo driver. So it seems that these two channels have an effect on each other.

Besides, there is not much weight on the tilt pane. And removing the weight does not seem to help.

init code:

```
pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();
pwm.begin();
pwm.setPWMFreq(60);  // Analog servos run at ~60 Hz updates
yield();
```

turning horizontally:

```
void Platform::setHorizontal(int d){
  if(d > 90)
    d = 90;
  if(d < -90)
    d = -90;
  point->setHorizontal(d);
  d = (d * 2.555) + 70.0; // calibrating.
  pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 325 + d); // 325 = (150 + 600) / 2
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by verifying the power supply is adequate, then go from there. If nothing else try a much bigger capacitor.

Comment: Changed the power supply with a more expensive one, Worked like a charm. I wish I could give you a Medal.